# Notice: Undefined Offset 1

Tags: php

This is my value in text field

`2013 TOYOTA Corolla (Blue) VIN:5YFBU4EE9DP082489`

text field is

`<input type="text" class="form-control" name="dockReceiptVinNo[]" id="dockReceiptVinNo_1" placeholder="Vin No">`

in php I'm using this code for explode my value based on colon (`:`) sign in `VIN` number and my php code is

```
$dockReceiptVinNoArray = isset($_POST["dockReceiptVinNo"]) ? $_POST["dockReceiptVinNo"] : array();
foreach($dockReceiptVinNoArray as $vinNoVal) {
     $vinNoValExplode = explode(":", $vinNoVal);
     $vinNoValExplodeIndexOne = $vinNoValExplode[1];
     $selectOrderForLoadingPlan = "SELECT fieldsname FROM tablename WHERE fieldname = '".$vinNoValExplodeIndexOne."'";
}
```

But the problem is I'm getting the error of undefined offset although I've the value in `1` index but its giving me the error, I don't know why? What is the wrong thing in my code, it seems ok to me, because I'm geeting value `5YFBU4EE9DP082489` in index `1` but don't know why it is saying `undefined offset 1`.

Note: I know that question is repeated several times but in my code I'm getting value and still it is saying undefined offset 1.

Comment: what is the output if you try `var_dump($vinNoValExplode)`?

Comment: I check the variable `$vinNoValExplode` and its says `vinNoValExplode: Array[2] 0: "2013 TOYOTA Corolla (Blue) VIN" and 1: "5YFBU4EE9DP082489"`.

Comment: Is it saying that for every element of the `$_POST['dockReceiptVinNo']` array? Are all the fields filled in with values like that?

Comment: Can you post `var_dump($_POST['dockReceiptVinNo'])`?

Comment: after this I check `$vinNoValExplode[1]` and it says `"5YFBU4EE9DP082489"` and last I check this variable `$vinNoValExplodeIndexOne` and it also says `"5YFBU4EE9DP082489"` then what is wrong with the code?

Comment: `$_POST['dockreceiptVinNo']` says `dockReceiptVinNo: Array[2] 0: "2013 TOYOTA Corolla (Blue) VIN:5YFBU4EE9DP082489"` and `1: "2004 MERCEDES ML350 (Black) VIN:5YFBU4EE9DP082490"`

Comment: post the full error message and look if the error line matches :)

Comment: This code `$vinNoValExplodeIndexOne = $vinNoValExplode[1];` is at line no `737` and error is `Notice Undefined Offset: 1 in path\filename on line 737`.